# Format text loaded from a .txt-file to a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView that fetches text from a plain .txt-file (using the code below).
I’ve tried to change the look of the text both in the interface builder and programmatically, but nothing works.

Is it not possible to format a text that is read from a txt-file?

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"plain3" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.myText setText:content];
```

Comment: "Change the look"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Larme change color, font, size etc.

Comment: The same for the whole text? If yes, `myText.font = theFontYouWant` (note that the size is included in the font), and for the color, `UITextView` has a property for it.

Comment: Elaborate your problem more in brief and in clear way

Comment: @Larme Thanks, that works great :). It's weird though, I tried that code earlier but didn't get it to work, must have placed it wrong. None of the changes I do in the interface builder works though, but now I can do it all programmatically. Thank you!